# htaccess file not working in php?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have a code and this code not working

this is htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{1,10000})-([a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,10000})$ news.php?id=$2&namenews=$3
```

and this is php code

```
<a href='$slidefetch->id_ar-$slidefetch->name_ar'>
```

Comment: You need to break into php and echo that. `<?php echo $slide... ?>`

Comment: holy… 10000 as a limit!

Comment: @Class - That's a lotta digits.  But who knows, maybe 20 years from now, it'll come in handy.

Comment: @moto I think you are misundertanding the use of `{1,10000}`, that means the amount of characters allowed, not the range of number. if you want up to 5 digits you can use `[0-9]{1,5}` which will allow numbers from 1 to 99999. **It would be easier if you show us an example of URL you want redirected.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you got a few things wrong. In the rewrite rule you have $2/3 when it should be $1/2. Plus you have {1,10000} which means min of 1 number to 100000 digits long! You might want to have like {1,6} or whatever your limit is. Also I believe there is a limit on the length of a url which is ~2000 characters long depending on browser/search engine, but its better to keep them shorter!

if you want actually 1-10000 you can try:

```
RewriteRule ^([1-9][0-9]{0,3}|10000)-([a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,6})$ news.php?id=$1&namenews=$2
```

Otherwise:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{1,6})-([a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,6})$ news.php?id=$1&namenews=$2
             (----$1----) (-------$2--------)
```

I'm not sure if you have a echo for your a tag but you should do something like:

```
echo '<a href="', $slidefetch->id_ar, '-', $slidefetch->name_ar, '">';
```

Comment: i have "single.php?id=1" i want it "1-name news.html" in htaccess file and php code .